# How to Lock a particular cell in XSSF Work Book so user could not edit that

Tags: apache, apache-poi, xssf

I am using Apache POI to read and Write XSSF WorkBook.

On click on a button a file needs to be Generated (XSSF Workbook with 5 sheets in it, .xlsm extension) its having 50 columns, out of which I am populating 4 of the Columns .... Now once this file is saved in users system these 4 columns data which my code populated should be non editable(Strictly only these 4,remaining 46 Columns user should be able to edit the data). How to Achieve that??? (I Can use Latest Apache POI)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the cell style to locked or unlocked and protect the sheet. Locking the sheet will default all cells to read-only.

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet)workbook.createSheet("worksheet");
sheet.protectSheet("password");


CellStyle lockedStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
lockedStyle.setLocked(true); 

CellStyle defaultStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
defaultStyle.setLocked(false);

// Create a header row
Row row = sheet.createRow(0);    
Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("locked");
cell.setCellStyle(lockedStyle);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

cell = row.createCell(1);
cell.setCellValue("this cell unlocked");
cell.setCellStyle(defaultStyle);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(1);

cell = row.createCell(2);
cell.setCellValue("this column unlocked");
cell.setCellStyle(defaultStyle);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(2);

// sets any auto-generated cells in this column to unlocked
sheet.setDefaultColumnStyle(2, defaultStyle);

FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream("doc.xlsx");
workbook.write(fileOut);

workbook.close();
fileOut.close();
```